# Using a formula in a cell but importing the value into Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I have a list of numbers and the first 3 numbers are an identifier which I pull out and set in a different column.  I then want to take this spreadsheet and import it into Access and because I use

```
=left(A2,3)
```

as the formula I have a hard time importing it into access.  My workaround I created is

```
Worksheets("Data").Range("C2:C2520").Value = "=LEFT(A2,3)"
Worksheets("Data").Range("C2:C2520").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("C2:C2520").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

This works but I was wondering If there is a simpler way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not *much* simpler but avoids the copy/paste:

```
With Worksheets("Data").Range("C2:C2520")
    .Formula = "=LEFT(A2,3)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Perfect workaround for me I knew the copy and paste wasn't the most efficient way